# Angular Material Dialog - content projection

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog, projection

Is it possible to use dynamic content inside an [angular material dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)?

```
let dialogRef = dialog.open(YourDialog, {
  data: { name: 'austin' },
});
```

Instead of `{ name: 'austin' }`, I would like to use a dynamic template which includes **html tags**.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your-dialog',
  template: 'passed in {{ data.name }}',
  // template: '{{ data.template }}'
})
export class YourDialog {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes just instead of use {{ }} use something like this

```
[innerHTML]="data.template"
```

in a div for example